# SLIM Error :: AuthController not found when SLIM app hosted on server

Tags: php, rest, slim, shared-hosting, slim-3

**I have a REST api app using SLIM framework.
Below is my app dir structure**
[image]

**Below is structure in my controllers dir**

[image]

**Authcontroller.php is in Auth folder.**

**Below are namespaces given to ActionController and Authcontroller**
[image] 
[image]

**Both controllers (Action and Auth) are defined in container as below in the mainapp**
[image]

Above app is working fine on my localhost ,but when i **upload same to my server, it get below error on above line 58**
[image]

Please help me here , i am going mad,have changed around 3 hosting servers(SHARED-HOSTING),but still same error. **PLEASE HELP!!**

Comment: Please don't include screenshot of code or error messages. Instead, you can paste the text for your code or error message in the question and format it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your deployment server is Linux, mostly, because path is case-sensitive.

If your `composer.json` contains section such as below

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app"
    },
},
...
```

Composer PSR-4 autoloading expect to find class

```
\App\Controllers\Auth\AuthController
```

in file

```
 app\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
```

but it can not find it because yours is

```
 app\controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
```

Since your development machine seems to use Windows which by default is case-insensitive,

```
 app\controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
```

equals to

```
 app\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
```

Which is why it works on your development machine but not on deployment server.

So the solution is to rename any directory/files to match its case and also make sure that all files is copied to deployment server.

After you change directory/filename case, run

`$ composer dump-autoload`

So new autoload file is generated.

Comment: Thanks @Zamrony  , this solved my problem finally :) Thanks Man!!